# ESLint parsing error when using arrow syntax with async

Tags: eslint

I'm using ESLint to analyze my code. The code runs fine, but I get this error from `eslint`:

```
[eslint] Parsing error: Unexpected token t

(parameter) t: any

test.serial('set: Handles save error', async t => {
  // function definition
});
```

Here's `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'google',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6
  }
};
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`async`/`await` is an ECMAScript 2017 feature, so if you change `ecmaVersion: 8` instead of 6, this should work!

Comment: I had `"env": {"es6": true}` in my `eslintrc.json` file. I needed to switch `es6` to `es7`

Comment: I had `"env": { "es2021": true}` in my `eslintrc.json` file. I needed to switch es2021 to es2022

Comment: Changing `"env": {"es6": true}` or `"env": {"es2021": true}` to es7 or es2022 resulted in compile fail with 'Environment key  [...] is unknown` using create-react-app.

Answer (score 1):

I  had a similar problem and solve editing the package.json line 5.

I removed " ." that's after "eslint" and everything is fine now.

Comment: This saved my day! Thank you! I do not understand why they added it there to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You may have this error even if you use latest version of ECMAScript if that is the case (like it was with me) the problem may be in your configuration:

```
"space-before-function-paren": [
  "error",
  "never"
]
```

if you have this you should make a change to:

```
"space-before-function-paren": [
  "error",
  {
    "anonymous": "never",
    "named": "never",
    "asyncArrow": "always"
  }
],
```

You can find this in this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/13983).