# Eslint shows error when using "async" in the latest Node version for Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I am trying to use Firebase Functions in my project but I have not used Javascript before, so I am strugling for a week and now I can't go on because of the following.

Here is my code:

```
exports.postcleanup = onSchedule("every day 00:00",
    async (event) => {
        const db = admin.database();
        const dbRef = db.ref();
        const posts = [];
        await dbRef.child("/allPosts").get().
            then((snapshot) => {
                if (snapshot.exists) {
                    posts.push(snapshot.val);
                    console.log("log on functions: " + posts.toString);
                } else {
                    console.log("No posts to delete");
                }
            }
            ).catch((error) => {
                console.log("error deleting old posts\n" + error);
            }
            );
        console.log("teste");
    }
);
```

When I use the command in the terminal: `functions/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js . --fix`,I get the following error message:

```
 12:19  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

But when I don't use the async/await keywords, the error disappear.
I checked my Node version and it seems updated:
`node -v` => v19.0.0 , `sudo node -v` => v16.18.0

Please, can you help me, guys?

Comment: A better tag for this question would be **eslint**, I think.  Your code looks like it should work except for the fact that you don't seem to fully understand async/await in JavaScript.  You see, you can just await the call to `get()` and stop using `.then()`.  Doing async/await is interpreter candy for promise chaining.

Comment: Thanks @JoséRamírez. Actually it was just a test code, I understand that using async/await and try/catch dismiss the use of then().catch.
But I found out the problem, it was ecmaversion on configuration file. I will post the full answer =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the version of ecmaversion. I got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44523845/17993781

Just include the below code in the file .eslintrc.js and it should recognize async/await syntax.

parserOptions: {
"ecmaVersion": 8,
},

example:

```
extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
  },
```

Comment: See?  It was indeed an es-lint related question.  Tags are important!  Cheers.